# Why isn't a client-side HTTP.get() call working in Cordova (Meteor 0.9.3)?

Tags: api, cordova, meteor

UPDATED QUESTION:
A simple client-side HTTP.get() call is not working on the iOS emulator. The same call is fetching data and its displaying perfectly in my templates in the browser (localhost:3000)
Earlier I thought this got to do with local collections, but the problem is actually with the HTTP.get call which is not returning any data within cordova (ios emulator or device).

Please note that my entire code is only on the client if (Meteor.isClient) {} and nothing in if (Meteor.isCordova) {}.

ORIGINAL QUESTION: Is it possible to define a local collection in Cordova (Meteor 0.9.3)?
I have a local(client-only) collection in my app as shown: 
Items = new Meteor.Collection(null);

This local collection temporarily gets data from an external API ( by adding 'meteor add http' and using HTTP.get() ) and this content is pushed to the templates. This is appearing perfectly in the browser templates on localhost:3000 through the helpers ( return Items.find() ), but when I run 'meteor run ios', the data is not loading up in the iOS simulator.

First of all, is it even possible to expect a local collection to work within Cordova?
Should this be defined inside:
Meteor.isCordova({ })?
Does it require a cordova-specific package to be added?
I believe a local collection is necessary in this case because the data is retrieved based on the user's device location and its relevant only for the current session.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

(meteor noob here, sorry if this sounds stupid!)

EDIT: Collections defined both on the server and client are working in the browser as well as on iOS emulator. So the problem is only with local collections.

Comment: I don't think there is anything special about Cordova and local collections. You probably have some other bug, like not connecting to server or not having CORS headers to talk to external services as the cordova code is served from a different origin.

Comment: @imslavko Sorry, I should have mentioned I'm able to access Collections defined both on the server and client in the iOS emulator (like in a common 'collections' folder in my folder structure). Which means the cordova part of my app is running correctly. And also, the CORS headers is handled by a Chrome browser plugin. So I'm reasonably sure its a problem only when local collections are used.

Comment: I don't know what is the Chrome browser plugin you are talking about.

Comment: @imslavko Its a chrome extension which lets you enable/disable CORS. This is the one: [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/details)

Answer (score 2):

@imslavko
You're indeed right! Its the CORS issue on the server to which I was making the API call.
After a couple of days of breaking my head, I eventually figured out the server did not have  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * for simple GET/POST requests.

Thanks for your help in figuring this out.

So it turns out Cordova has nothing to do with this. All HTTP.get() calls are working perfectly from within Cordova too including local collections.

Answer (score 0):

There's one more trick to be aware of.

`HTTP.get('/route')` will likely end up in the phones local server instead of the remote server the data comes from - so you wont be receiving the data you'd expect.

Instead use

```
HTTP.get(__meteor_runtime_config__.ROOT_URL + '/route')
```

Because the ROOT_URL variable points to the correct server in both Cordova apps and normal browsers.